# ExecutorService shutdown other threads when one of them returns not null

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have like `20` threads. Each of the threads just makes `findOne` query to `MongoDB`:

```
db.myCollection.findOne({"queryKey" : "queryValue"})
```

So `findOne` is going to return either `null` of found document.

Whenever one of the threads returns found document instead of `null`, I want to shutdown other threads.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried using [`invokeAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection)) in `ExecutorService`. But it's returning the result of one that has completed ***successfully***. In my case ***successful***  case is when `findOne` returns found document instead of `null`.

**Note:** My real example is more complicated than just `findOne`( that's why I'm using multithreading, instead of just sequential calls)

Comment: You could throw an exception if the task returns `null`, so the one that returns some document would be successful one from the point of view of `invokeAny()`

Comment: The class you are looking for is called ExecutorCompletionService https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the definition of `invokeAny`, the first successful result is returned. To make this work in your use-case wrap `findOne` and throw an exception if it is `null`, making it non-successful.